# How can I properly install Debian on a laptop that used to have windows? (There is probably a problem with MBR)

Tags: debian, debian-installer, mbr, nas

I recently broke the screen of my Lenovo Ideapad 110S-11IBR, so I decided to use it as a NAS device.
After I tried to install a Debian-based NAS operating system I ran into a problem: Even though the installation was successful, when I tried to boot, the system could not detect any OS. I used a partitioning tool's live USB in order to test if the operating system was installed and it was. I tried other Linux distributions and I had the exact same problem. Something interesting I noticed was that in the boot options, I had the disk and "Windows Boot Manager." I tried DBAN in order to fully wipe the disk and possibly get rid of "Windows Boot Manager", but DBAN failed to locate the disk. I also installed Windows in order to check if it would boot correctly and it did.
If anyone has any idea about what to do, it would be much appreciated

Note: the "disk" I am talking about is the internal 32Gb disk.

Comment: Do you mean boot option in `UEFI`? Did you install a bootloader on the hard drive? How did you install (e.g. via a live version or an installation USB)?

Comment: @Fiximan I installed GRUB from the Debian USB stick (Debian 10 i386 netinst)

Comment: Perhaps the internal disk was already close to failure and the sustained writes involved in the OS installation caused it to finally fail completely? Or maybe the 32 GB disk is actually a SD card, requiring a SD card controller driver that might not be included in DBAN.

Comment: @telcoM The drive has not failed because I could install Windows. Yesterday I found out that it is recognised as an SD/MMC card but I cannot understand why grub can't work on it.

Comment: @telcoM Thank you, it worked. please rewrite your comment as an answer so i canmark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question comments, you confirmed that the internal 32 GB disk is actually a SD/MMC card.

The presence of "Windows Boot Manager" indicates the system is UEFI capable, and that Windows was installed to boot in UEFI mode.

Perhaps the laptop is currently configured to prefer booting in legacy BIOS-compatible mode (causing you to install the NAS in BIOS mode unless you're extra careful in booting the installer), but the SD/MMC boot support in the system firmware is only implemented for the UEFI mode?

Check the BIOS settings, set it to boot "UEFI only" if possible, and try the installer again. Or maybe the NAS operating system installer is legacy BIOS boot only?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [GRUB-Bootloader](https://wiki.debian.org/Grub). It can handle Windows and Debian.

Comment: Thank you but as far as I know the bootloader is installed in the last part of the installation progress. If that is correct, I have selected to install it. I don't know if it was clear but I don't want to use Windows at all

Comment: Ok, then boot from live USB, wipe the whole disk --> not only partitions but the whole disk --> then reinstall Debian

Comment: How should I do that? As I said, DBAN does not work.

Comment: [link](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) --> for example